# Eagerly Loading is not loading the relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to use Eagerly Loading to load needed data. but it is not working. When I use:

```
 Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = True;
```

it load all the relation tables but I want to limit that so I changed the true to false and Try to load the relationships, but it is not loaded.

This is my code:

```
     public CommonsController(ICreditApplicationsContext creditApplicationsContext)
    {

        if(creditApplicationsContext != null)
        {
            this.creditApplicationsContext = creditApplicationsContext;

         creditApplicationsContext.Years.Include("Makes");
         creditApplicationsContext.Makes.Include("Models");
         creditApplicationsContext.Models.Include("Trims");
         }
        else
        {
            this.creditApplicationsContext = new CreditApplicationsContext();

        }
        this.creditApplicationsRepository = new CreditApplicationsRepository(this.creditApplicationsContext);     
    }
```

I am putting this code in the page that uses the Context, I tries to put it in the Context but same problem.

Comment: `Include` doesn't modify the context, it is returning an `IQueryable<>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the results of your call to a variable:

try

```
var Years = creditApplicationsContext.Years.Include("Makes").ToList();
```

You can put a breakpoint on that line and step through, `Years` should now be populated and include the `Makes` objects as well.